How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \ln ^3(1+x) \ln (1-x) d x$?

QUESTION:
How to evaluate

$$\int_0^1 \ln ^3(1+x) \ln (1-x) d x$$?

Background

I'm not sure of the closed form of the integral, as I haven't evaluated it yet. However, after evaluating the integral $$\int_0^1 \ln (1+x) \ln (1-x) \, dx,$$ I thought about integrating $$\int_0^1 \ln^3(1+x) \ln (1-x) \, dx.$$
I am also interested in evaluation of $$\int_0^1 \ln^n(1+x) \ln (1-x) \, dx.$$ If possible

Here is my attempt

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^1 \ln^3(1+x) \ln(1-x) \, dx, \\
a &= \ln(1-x), \quad b = \ln(1+x), \\
b^3 a &= \frac{1}{8}(a+b)^4 - \frac{1}{8}(a-b)^4 - a^3 b.
\end{align}
Using the above, the integral becomes:
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{8} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \ln^4(1-x^2) \, dx}_{A} \frac{1}{8} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \ln^4\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) \, dx}_{B} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \ln^3(1-x) \ln(1+x) \, dx}_{C}.
\end{align}
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ln^4(1-x) \, dx, \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{2}, a\right) \Bigg\{
\left[\psi^{(0)}(a) - \psi^{(0)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^4 \\
&\quad + 6 \left[\psi^{(1)}(a) - \psi^{(1)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]
\left[\psi^{(0)}(a) - \psi^{(0)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2 \\
&\quad + 4 \left[\psi^{(2)}(a) - \psi^{(2)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]
\left[\psi^{(0)}(a) - \psi^{(0)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right] \\
&\quad + 3 \left[\psi^{(1)}(a) - \psi^{(1)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2 \psi^{(3)}(a) - \psi^{(3)}\left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right) \Bigg\} \Big|_{a=1}.
\end{align}
Using:
\begin{align}
\psi^{(0)}(1) &= -\gamma, \quad \psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = 2 - 2 \ln(2) - \gamma, \\
\psi^{(n)}(1) - \psi^{(n)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) &= (-1)^{n+1} n! \left[ 2^{n+1} + \left(2 - 2^{n+1}\right) \zeta(n+1) \right].
\end{align}
Substitute these to find:
\begin{align}
A &= (2 \ln(2) - 2)^4 + 6(4 - 2 \zeta(2))(2 \ln(2) - 2)^2 \\
&\quad + 4(12 \zeta(3) - 16)(2 \ln(2) - 2) + 3(4 - 2 \zeta(2))^2 + 96 - 84 \zeta(4).
\end{align}
\begin{align}
A &= -48 \ln^2(2) \zeta(2) + 96 \ln(2)(\zeta(3) + \zeta(2)) + 16 \ln^4(2) \\
&\quad - 64 \ln^3(2) + 192 \ln^2(2) - 54 \zeta(4) - 96 \zeta(3) \\
&\quad - 96 \zeta(2) - 384 \ln(2) + 384.
\end{align}
Evaluating ￼
\begin{align}
B &= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(x)}{(1+x)^2} \, dx
= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-1)^{n-1} \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \ln^4(x) \, dx \\
&= \left. 2 \frac{\partial^4}{\partial a^4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(-1)^{n-1}}{n+a-1} \right|{a=1}
= 2 \cdot 4! \underbrace{\sum{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4}}_{\eta(4)} \\
&\Rightarrow B = 42 \zeta(4).
\end{align}
Evaluating ￼
\begin{align}
C &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \int_0^1 x^n \ln^3(1-x) \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}
\left(\frac{H_{n+1}^3 + 3 H_{n+1} H_{n+1}^{(2)} + 2 H_{n+1}^{(3)}}{n+1}\right).
\end{align}
Split ￼ into three terms:
\begin{align}
C &= \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_{n+1}^3}{n(n+1)}}_D
  3 \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_{n+1} H_{n+1}^{(2)}}{n(n+1)}}_E
  2 \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_{n+1}^{(3)}}{n(n+1)}}_F.
\end{align}
\begin{align}
D &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \left(H_n + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^3}{n}
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} H_{n+1}^3}{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \left(H_n^3 + 3 \frac{H_n^2}{n+1} + 3 \frac{H_n}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)}{n} \\
&\quad + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n^3}{n}.
\end{align}
Expanding:
\begin{align}
D &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n^3}{n} 6 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n^2}{n} 6 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n} \\
&\quad - 3 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^2}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3} 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} + 4.
\end{align}
￼
Using known series expansions:
\begin{align}
D &= 2\left(\frac{9 \ln(2) \zeta(3)}{8} - \frac{3 \ln^2(2) \zeta(2)}{4} \frac{\ln^4(2)}{4} - \frac{5 \zeta(4)}{8}\right) \\
&\quad + 6\left(\frac{\ln(2) \zeta(2)}{2} - \frac{\ln^3(2)}{3} - \frac{3 \zeta(3)}{4}\right) 6\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2} - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}\right) \\
&\quad - 3\left(-\frac{5 \zeta(3)}{8}\right) \frac{3 \zeta(3)}{4} 2\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}\right)
2(\ln(2)) + 4.
\end{align}
Simplify further:
\begin{align}
D &= \frac{9 \ln(2) \zeta(3)}{4} - \frac{3 \ln^2(2) \zeta(2)}{2} 3 \ln(2) \zeta(2) + \frac{\ln^4(2)}{2} - 2 \ln^3(2) \\
&\quad + 3 \ln^2(2) - \frac{5 \zeta(4)}{4} \frac{27 \zeta(3)}{8} - 2 \zeta(2) 2 \ln(2) + 4.
\end{align}
\begin{aligned}
& E=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\left(H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(H_n^{(2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n H_n^{(2)}}{n} \\
& =2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n H_n^{(2)}}{n}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n(n+1)^2}}_G+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n^{(2)}}{n(n+1)}}_H+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)^3}}_J+1 \\
& \star \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n H_n^{(2)}}{n}=-2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{7 \ln (2) \zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{\ln ^2(2) \zeta(2)}{4}-\frac{\ln ^4(2)}{12}+\zeta(4) \\
& G=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n} \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\left(H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{(n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\left(H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n} \\
& =\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^2}}_{-\frac{5 \zeta(3)}{8}}+2 \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n}}_{\frac{\ln ^2(2)}{2}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}}+\eta(3)+\eta(2) \Rightarrow G=\ln ^2(2)+\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2} \\
& H=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n^{(2)}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\left(H_{n+1}^{(2)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)}{n+1} \\
& =2 \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n^{(2)}}{n}}_{\frac{\ln (2) \zeta(2)}{2}-\zeta(3)}+\eta(3) \Rightarrow H=\ln (2) \zeta(2)-\frac{5 \zeta(3)}{4} \ldots(\mu) \\
& J=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}}_{1-\eta(3)}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}_{1-\eta(2)}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}}_{1-\ln (2)}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}}_{-\ln (2)} \\
& \Rightarrow J=-\frac{3 \zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}-2 \ln (2)+3 \ldots(\nu)
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
* & \text { Replacing }(\theta),(\lambda),(\mu),(\nu) \rightarrow(\varepsilon): \\
\Rightarrow & E=-4 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{7 \ln (2) \zeta(3)}{4}+\frac{\ln ^2(2) \zeta(2)}{2}+\ln (2) \zeta(2) \\
& -\frac{\ln ^4(2)}{6}+\ln ^2(2)+2 \zeta(4)-\frac{15 \zeta(3)}{8}-\zeta(2)-2 \ln (2)+4 \ldots(\rho) \\
F & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\left(H_n^{(3)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n^{(3)}}{n} \\
= & 2 \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_n^{(3)}}{n}}_{n=1}+\underbrace{\frac{3 \ln (2) \zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{19 \zeta(4)}{16}} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)^3}+1 \\
\Rightarrow & F=\frac{3 \ln (2) \zeta(3)}{2}-\frac{19 \zeta(4)}{8}-\frac{3 \zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}-2 \ln (2)+4 \ldots(\sigma) \\
* & \operatorname{Replacing}(\delta),(\rho),(\sigma) \rightarrow(\gamma): \\
\Rightarrow & C=-12 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+6 \ln (2) \zeta(2)-2 \ln ^3(2)+6 \ln ^2(2) \\
& -\frac{21 \zeta(3)}{2}-6 \zeta(2)-12 \ln (2)+24 \ldots(\omega)
\end{aligned}
*Replacing $(\alpha),(\beta),(\omega) \rightarrow(\varphi)$ and using the following equivalence (Borwein, Borwein & Girgensohn 1995):
$$
\star \mathrm{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\ln ^2(2) \zeta(2)}{4}-\frac{\ln ^4(2)}{24}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\zeta(\overline{3}, \overline{1})}{2}
$$
We obtain the final result of the integral:
\begin{aligned}
\therefore & I=12\left(\ln ^2(2)-\frac{1}{8}\right) \zeta(3)+\frac{3}{2} \ln ^4(2)-6 \ln ^3(2) \\
& +\ln ^2(2)(18-3 \zeta(2))+(\zeta(2)-6) 6 \ln (2)+24-9 \zeta(4) \\
& -6 \zeta(2)-6 \zeta(\overline{3}, \overline{1})
\end{aligned}
$\mathrm{B}^{(n)}(a, b) \rightarrow$ nth derivative of the beta function
$\zeta\left(\overline{s_1}, \overline{s_2}, \cdots \overline{s_k}\right) \rightarrow$ Alternating multiple zeta value
I.A

fyi, there is a closed form integral of $\ln^3(1+x)\ln(1-x)$ which would only require you to calculate $Li_k((x+1)/2)$ for $k=2,3,4$ at the boundary conditions $x=0$, and $x=1$, that is when evaluating $\int_0^1$. You will need $\zeta(2), \zeta(3), \zeta(4)$  to write the answer, and the normal elementary operations such as multiplication, addition, logarithms, integer powers of logarithms.

There is a method in the polylog integral solver I used that allowed me to find the form, and prove that its derivative was exactly your integrand and therefore allowing me to write your integral in terms of a final number solution. I was able to do this quickly due to my superior tooling, and the proof is valid since the differentiation is easy to compute and verify it is indeed the integral, however, I don't think it would be a good idea to spend multiple hours trying to write this integral out by hand.

@Snared The current answer doesn't contain $\zeta(3)$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Integral B.}}$
$$I_B=\int\limits_0^1 \ln^4\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\,\text dx
=16\int\limits_0^1 \operatorname{arctanh}^4 x\,\text dx
=\dfrac7{15}\pi^4,$$
$$I_B\approx 45.45757\ 58158\ 67804\ 04367\ 21552\ 54729.$$
Really,
$$I_B=16\int\limits_0^1 \operatorname{arctanh}^4 x\,\text dx
=16\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{t^4\,\text dt}{\cosh^2t}
=64\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{t^4\,e^{-2t}\,\text dt}{\left(1+e^{-2t}\right)^2}$$
$$=64\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} k\int\limits_0^\infty t^4 e^{-2kt}\,\text dt
=64\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} k\cdot \dfrac3{4k^5}$$
$$=48\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^4}
=\dfrac7{15}\pi^4.$$
$\color{brown}{\textbf{Main integral.}}$
Substitution
$$x=e^t-1,\quad \text dx=e^t\text dt,\quad \ln(1+x)=t,$$
$$I=\int\limits_0^1 \ln^3(1+x)\ln(1-x)\,\text dx
=\int\limits_0^{\ln2} t^3 e^t \ln\left(2-e^{t}\right)\,\text dt$$
$$=\int\limits_0^{\ln2} t^3 e^t \left(\ln2+\ln\left(1-\frac12e^t\right)\right)\,\text dt=I_0+I_1,$$
where
$$I_0=\ln 2\int\limits_0^{\ln2}t^3 e^t\,\text dt,\quad I_1=\int\limits_0^{\ln2} t^3 e^t \ln\left(1-\frac12e^t\right)\,\text dt.\tag1$$
Then
$$I_0=\ln2\cdot e^t\left(t^3-3t^2+6t-6\right)\bigg|_0^{\ln2}
=2(\ln2)^4-6(\ln2)^3+12(\ln2)^2-12\ln2+6\ln2,$$
$$I_0=2\ln^4(2)-6\ln^3(2)+12\ln^2(2)-6\ln2.\tag2$$
Also,
$$I_1=\int\limits_0^{\ln2} t^3 e^t \ln\left(1-\frac12e^t\right)\,\text dt
=-\int\limits_0^{\ln2} t^3 e^t \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1k\dfrac{e^{kt}}{2^k}
\,\text dt
=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{-k}}{k}\,I_{1,k+1},$$
where
$$I_{1,k}=\int\limits_0^{\ln2} t^3 e^{kt}\text dt
=\dfrac1{k^4}\int\limits_0^{\ln2} (kt)^3 e^{kt}\text d(kt)
=\dfrac1{k^4}\int\limits_0^{k\ln2} t^3 e^{t}\text dt$$
$$=\dfrac1{k^4}e^t\left(t^3-3t^2+6t-6\right)\bigg|_0^{k\ln2}$$
$$=\dfrac6{k^4}+2^k\left(\dfrac{\ln^3(2)}{k}-\dfrac{3\ln^2(2)}{k^2}+\dfrac{6\ln2}{k^3}-\dfrac{6}{k^4}\right),$$
Let
$$J_0=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{-k}}{k}\,\dfrac6{(k+1)^4}
=-24+π^2(1-\ln(2))-6\ln^2(2)$$
$$+2\ln^3(2)+\ln(64) +12\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\dfrac12\right)+\dfrac{21}2 ζ(3),$$

$$\begin{align}
&J_1=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\ln^3(2)}{k(k+1)}=-2\ln^3(2),\\[4pt] &J_2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{6\ln^2(2)}{k(k+1)^2}=(12-\pi^2)\ln^2(2),\\[4pt]
&J_3=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{12\ln(2)}{k(k+1)^3}=2\ln(2)(π^2-18+6 ζ(3)),\\[4pt]
&J_4=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{12}{k(k+1)^4}=48-2\pi^2-\dfrac2{15}π^4- 12ζ(3).
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
&I_1=J_0+J_1+J_2+J_3+J_4=24-\pi^2-\dfrac2{15}\pi^4-\dfrac32\zeta(3) \\[4pt]
&+\big(\pi^2-30+12\zeta(3)\big)\ln(2)+(6-\pi^2)\ln^2(2) +12\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\dfrac12\right),
\end{align}\tag3$$
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\begin{align}&I=24-\pi^2-\dfrac2{15}\pi^4-\dfrac32\zeta(3)+\big(\pi^2-36+12\zeta(3)\big)\ln(2)+(18-\pi^2)\ln^2(2)\\[4pt]
&-6\ln^3(2)+2\ln^4(2)+12\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\dfrac12\right)\approx -0.19480\ 62619\ 27738\ 36514\ 85561\ 20791.\end{align}\tag4}}$$
Obtained result corresponds with WA calculations.


Fantastic answer,but are you sure $$\int\limits_0^1 \ln^4\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right),\text dx
=\dfrac1{16}\int\limits_0^1 \arctan^4 x,\text dx$$?

@Martin.s Thanks,! Ready.

Solution for integral B
Letting $t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^1 \ln ^4 t \frac{2 d t}{(1+t)^2} \\
& =2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^4 t}{(1+t)^2} d t\\&= \left. I^{(4)}(a)\right|_{a=0}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =\int_0^1 \frac{t^a}{(1+t)^2} d t \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} n \int_0^1 t^{a+n-1} d t \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} n}{a+n}
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t.$a$ by four times at $a=0$ yields $$
\begin{aligned}
I^{(4)}(0) & =\left.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x(-1)^4 4!}{(a+n)^5}\right|_{a=0} \\
& =24 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4}\\
& =24\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n)^4}\right] \\
& =21 \zeta(4) \\
& =\frac{21 \pi^4}{90} \\
& =\frac{7 \pi^4}{30}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence we get
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \ln ^4\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) d x=2 \cdot \frac{7 \pi^4}{30}=\frac{7 \pi^4}{15}}
$$
In general,

$$\int_0^1 \ln ^n\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) d x=(-1)^n 2 n!\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right) \zeta(n)$$


Thanks a lot!!!

Impressive and so simple ......after reading it !!

Thank you for your support!  The general case can be easily obtained by differentiating $I(a)$ by $n$ times at $a=0$ as above.

Too long for a comment: For a first solution, use a similar strategy to the one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4917671.
For a second solution, based on reducing the calculations to harmonic series, combine
$$\log^3(1+x) = \sum (-1)^n  \frac{{x}^{n + 1}}{n + 1} (H_n^2 - H_n^{(2)})$$
together with the integral identity
$$\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(1-x) dx = - \frac{H_n}{n},$$
both presented in (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019). If interested, similar and powerful identities also involving skew-harmonic numbers can be found in the sequel, More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2023).

$$I=\int_0^1 \ln ^4 t \frac{d t}{(1+t)^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^4 t}{(1+t)^2} d t=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)t^n\ln^4tdt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{24}{(n+1)^4}=\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5).
$$
